# How to change the function of F1 hotkey?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, hotkeys, function-keys

I have an hp pavilion running Windows 10 64 bit. The `F1` has an interrogation mark on it and if clicked, it opens a new Bing search tab.

I want to change what the button does, I don't want to disable it completely, because I might need it, it's just that every once in a while I click it by mistake and it's so annoying.

I don't want to have to use `fn` either. All I want to do is change what `f1` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best choice may be to utilize [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/):

> AutoHotkey (AHK) is a free, open-source macro-creation and automation software for Windows that allows users to automate repetitive tasks. It is driven by a scripting language that was initially aimed at providing keyboard shortcuts, otherwise known as hotkeys, that over time evolved into a full-fledged scripting language. And if you're really interested, here's a great video about it [here](https://youtu.be/lIFE7h3m40U?t=2m50s).
>
> You can use AutoHotkey to:
>
> - Automate almost anything by sending keystrokes and mouse clicks.
>     You can write a [mouse or keyboard macro](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Macros.htm) by hand or a macro recorder.
> - [Remap](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) keys and buttons on your keyboard, joystick, and mouse.
> - Create [hotkeys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) for keyboard, joystick, and mouse. Essentially any key, button or combination can become a hotkey.
> - [Expand abbreviations](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) as you type them. For example, typing "btw" can automatically produce "by the way".
> - Retrieve and change the [clipboard's contents](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm).
> - Convert any AHK script into an [executable file](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe) that can be run on computers where AutoHotkey is not installed.
> - Don't know where to start or how to fix your script? Join the friendly [AutoHotkey community](https://autohotkey.com/boards/) and ask for help

([Source](https://autohotkey.com/))

Comment: I guessed that, but I don't know how to do it, especially that some people on microsoft forums claim the f1 function is hardcoded, you either have to disable it completely or leave it as it is

Comment: As I referenced above, there are tutorials on their web site along with a very supportive community on their forums.  Needless to say, there isn't any hurry for an official answer to this question.  Personally, I would look into the AutoHotkey possibilities.  If it doesn't work out, someone else will probably step forward with a viable suggestion.

Comment: True, I accepted this answer, because I believe that autohotkey is the answer too, if someone has a better I'm gonna have to accept his, but I doubt it, I believe autohotkey is the only solution

Comment: So is that key sending an F1 or some other function?  Try installing AutoHotkey and running an example script that's persistent. From the tray icon, open the script that's running and then from the View menu look at the key history before/after pressing the F1 key.  From there you should be able to remap the key as needed.  Post follow-up or a separate post if you need further help.