# Change the function of Alt+Shift on Windows to the Caps Lock (Like the way it works on High Sierra)

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, input-languages, button-remapping

As you may know, the **switch language input keys is "Caps Lock" on latest OSx, High Sierra**. I really liked this change because I rarely use caps lock but I have to switch between two languages thousand times a day!

In Windows, we have to push *Alt+Shift* or *Win+Space* together to switch language typing and I use both Mac & PC, so it makes me confuse while I switch between PC & Mac!

> *Anyway, the way we change the input method in High Sierra on Mac is
>   much more easy and I'm sure that most PC users will love it!*

Is there a way to change the switch input method shortcut of Windows (Alt+Shift or Windows+Space) to only Caps-lock key?

---

PS:
In Mac, press and hold the Caps Lock enables typing in all uppercase. It would be nice if we have it on the Windows, too. but it doesn't matter for me if I lose this one at all!

Comment: Within the Windows world, many of us utilize [AutoHotkey](https://superuser.com/questions/1164799/how-to-change-the-function-of-f1-hotkey/1164800#1164800) to do something like that.

Comment: Thanks but I need its function on whole OS not only in MS.World.

Comment: I think that there is a small misunderstanding.  When I say *"Within the Windows world,"* that is simply a figure of speech.  In other words, that **does** apply to the whole OS.  Take a look at AutoHotkey, and you should be able to do exactly what you want.

Comment: oh oh sorry! I'm a bit sleepy and read that WORD :)) 
thanks alot, I'm reading [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) to find out how can I write a simple script for do that.

Comment: My caps lock in High Sierra is not acting as a language switcher; it's acting as a regular caps lock. Are you sure you didn't set this somewhere?

Comment: @seaturtle you're right. it has came in latest version of MacOS and doesn't enabled by default. if you can't find it, let me know, I'll search in its settings.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Run5k](https://superuser.com/users/650163/run5k) & [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) I found the solution.

1. Install the **AutoHotKey** and Run it
2. Run > shell:startup (Startup folder will open)

   > *You can keep it in the 'Startup folder' to run automatically at the Windows boot.*
3. Right click > New > AutoHotkey script > choose a file name and open
4. Copy the below code into the text editor and save it:

   > ```
   > CapsLock::Send, {Alt Down}{Shift Down}{Shift Up}{Alt Up}
   > Return
   > ```
5. right click on the file > Run script

Now you will see the Caps Lock switches input language through every single push.

---

*PS: I'm trying to write a script to hold shift while I holding the Caps Lock for 2 seconds. Then I'll complete this post.*

Comment: I removed the green check mark because I found the code combination has some bugs and made conflict on other functionalities. I'll working on it and share the best code ASAP.