# Is there a way to use the "Windows Start Key" in a batch file in Windows 10 Pro 64 bit?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, batch-file

I wanted to make a batch file so I could add it to one of the 5 custom shortcut buttons on the top of my MS Erg 4000 Keyboard. The problem is that I want the button to put the computer to sleep and that requires me to use a Windows shortcut that needs the "Windows Start Key" and I don't know if it is possible to type some command that will tell the batch file to use that key.

For some odd reason they never included a sleep button on the Fractal Design Mini. I know I can tell Windows that hitting the power button puts the computer to sleep, and I'll go that route if I have to, but I'd like to assign a shortcut to a custom batch file so I can just hit one of the keys on my keyboard.

I think the full batch file would be something like,

"Windows Key + X"

"U" (U brings up the shutdown menu)

"S" (S selects the sleep option in the menu that opens when you hit the U key)

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  We are always glad to help, but this seems like a lot of time and effort devoted towards saving a minimal amount of time.  Even the [moderators on Microsoft's own forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power-winpc/how-to-make-a-shortcut-to-put-windows-10-in-sleep/3c1ec06c-4029-488e-89fe-6ef63fa2ebba) recommended the keyboard presses that you described. That being said, if you really want to focus your effort on accomplishing this, you can potentially use an [AutoHotkey](https://superuser.com/a/1164800/650163) script.

Comment: I found out through some snooping around in the MS Keyboard program that if you change the macro for one of the other shortcut keys, such as the search key, you can make a custom macro that allows you to do exactly what I want. The problem is that this option isn't offered for the custom keys for some reason. I have a file named Sleep.mhm that runs perfectly when I hit the search key but to use it with the custom keys I need to know which program file I need to run to run the .mhm macro and not just open it up. There must be one or hitting search wouldn't put the PC to sleep.

Comment: there's a command you can execute to put the pc to sleep. You can write that command in your batch file. Just google for `Put pc to sleep command line`

Comment: OK, I don't know how I got to this program but it must have been from using LPChip's google suggestion. It is a program called "Sleep.exe" and because it is a program you can set a custom key to go to it, or a shortcut of it. It instantly puts the computer to sleep. I haven't tried to see if it will still put the computer to sleep with Hibernate turned on. So far it seems to work like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your comment above, you downloaded a 3rd party util, which is unnecessary to put a Windows machine to sleep.

All you need to type is:

> %windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0

Comment: I read many posts regarding that method and there was a lot of negative responses to using it due to some certificate problem with rundll32.exe. It's apparently something that MS has an article on their site about but I didn't bother looking into it that deeply. I did see that the program is on Github and it works really fast. I hit the key on my keyboard and my computer is almost asleep before I can take my next breath. :) I decided to trust it due to the feedback on the program from various people and it being up on Github for a year.

Comment: Saw what program on Github? `rundll32.exe` is a built-in Windows command/EXE.

Comment: Sorry I was talking about Sleep.exe. Also, if you google rundll32 + sleep + Superuser you should get some results regarding the issue with the rundll32 file.